# validate and allow registration with database - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am looking for a way to allow user registration if their 'DNI' is registered in the database in the 'dni_id' table
I want to validate the registration if the user's ID is in the database

```
   protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'apellido' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'wsp' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'dni' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

**can you help me ?**

[image]

I don't know whether to do it with a new function in integrating an if condition or to do it in the same function validator array, help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Exists](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exists) method. The method verify if the field under validation must exist on a given database table.
You can use like this:

```
'dni' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'exists:dni_table_name,dni_id],
```